# Change server structure to be able to view files/folders in browser (Dedictaed server)

Tags: apache, linux, ftp

I'm trying to deploy Wordpress on a red hat Linux server (dedicated server).

I'm trying to access it using the normal URL structure [IP]/[rootfoldername]/[nameofthefile] but it's not working.

Note that Phpmyadmin is working file on the server.

Below you will find the default page of the server and the FTP view:

[image: Red Hat Default page]

[image: FTP view]
<sub>(source: [mailchimp.com](https://gallery.mailchimp.com/726e6331815ba7dff26370203/images/a7756421-2357-452c-8087-aeb0a43766b2.png))</sub>

Should I change the structure of the FTP?

Note that the GTA folder is the one that contains the WordPress files so I need to access it to be able to run the install wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Web servers don't make every file on a computer available.  That would be a huge security problem.   Rather, by default they make a single directory available.  As the message says, that directory is `/var/www/html`.   You have two options:

1. Move your content to `/var/www/html` instead of having it in `/home/myuser/GTA`
2. Reconfigure the web server to serve a different directory.  To do that you would change the `DocumentRoot` setting in your Apache configuration files.   On Redhat, that file is located at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Once you have a domain for your site I would recommend using virtual hosts.   That allows you to the the document root separately for each site that you are hosting. The default document root can still point to `/var/www/html` but you could add a virtual host for `example.com` that points its document root to `/home/myuser/GTA`.